# link p:schedule prev next button to p:calendar like google calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, calendar

when we click the prev or next navigations of p:schedule, i would like to move the selected date of the p:calendar (like in google calendar).

```
 <p:calendar mode="inline" navigator="true" id="inlineCal" widgetVar="searchCalVar"
    value="#{bean.miniCalDate}" style="width:200px;">
        <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{bean.handleDateSelect}" update="calendarselectedvalue accord" />
    </p:calendar>

    <p:schedule id="schedule"  value="#{bean.eventModel}"
    widgetVar="scheduleWidget" draggable="true" resizable="false" allDaySlot="true" slotMinutes="15" firstHour="9" initialDate="#{bean.miniCalDate}"    timeZone="UTC" view="agendaWeek" leftHeaderTemplate="today, ,prev,next" rightHeaderTemplate="agendaDay,agendaWeek,month">
    </p:schedule>
```

I tried

```
     $('.fc-button-next').click(function(){
        myFullCal = scheduleWidget.jq.children(":first");
        var view = myFullCal.fullCalendar('getView');
        if(view.name=='agendaDay')
        {
        //  var newDate=myFullCal.fullCalendar('getDate');
           // var newDate=new Date($(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('accord:calendarselectedvalue')).val());
//      var nextSelectedDate=new Date(newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate()+1));
        //var newMonth= newDate.getMonth()+1;
        //var year = newDate.getFullYear()+"";
        //var newYear=year.substring(2);
        //var nextDate=newDate.getDate()+'/'+newMonth+'/'+newYear;
        cal = searchCalVar.jq.children(":first");
        cal.input.val("27/6/14");
        }
    });
```

I have googled for the solution. But found nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess the below code solved my problem.

```
 $('.fc-button-next').click(function(){
             myFullCal = scheduleWidget.jq.children(":first");
                    var view = myFullCal.fullCalendar('getView');
                    if(view.name=='agendaDay')
                    {
                        var selectedDate=searchCalVar.getDate();
                        searchCalVar.setDate(null);
                        var nextDate=new Date(selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()+1));
                        searchCalVar.setDate(nextDate);
                     }
                });

                $('.fc-button-prev').click(function(){
                    myFullCal = scheduleWidget.jq.children(":first");
                    var view = myFullCal.fullCalendar('getView');
                    if(view.name=='agendaDay')
                    {
                        var selectedDate=searchCalVar.getDate();
                        searchCalVar.setDate(null);
                        var nextDate=new Date(selectedDate.setDate(selectedDate.getDate()-1));
                        searchCalVar.setDate(nextDate);
                     }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

I use Primefaces 5.2 and implemented a solution based on the example Lazy Schedule showcase. 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml

By clicking on the navigation buttons prev or next p: schedule, 
an event is generated that calls the init() method that receives 
the startDate dates and endDate p:calendar.
Each click invokes the method with new dates.

see a part of the sample code:

```
public void init() {         
   ScheduleModel lazyEventModel = new LazyScheduleModel() {             

        public void loadEvents(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
            Date random = getRandomDate(startDate);
            addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 1", random, random));                 
            random = getRandomDate(endDate);
            addEvent(new DefaultScheduleEvent("Lazy Event 2", random, random));
        }  
    };
}
```